# Monitoring server GET and PUT responses on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, get, pycharm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, put

I am struggling to work out how I can monitor my AWS EB server response to GET and PUT requests.

Most of my development work is done using PyCharm on a local server and this shows all of the GET/PUT responses.

I have moved a working Django/Python installation to my AWS EB instance and it is not responding properly to the PUT requests.

Is there a way to monitor the response on AWS?

Comment: Can you do it client-side with something like Chrome DevTools, Postman, or even PyCharm's REST Testing tool?

Comment: I have googled this but not found a solution

Comment: I can help on that, but I just want to know which direction you want to go. Do you want to verify the responses by looking at the client or the Django side?

Comment: I want to be able to monitor the PUT responses from the remote Django server on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

In that case, I would suggest using Chrome and the Chrome developer tools to watch the network connection responses.

Comment: I am wanting to monitor my AWS EB instances GET and PUT responses to requests from other users.